# Prism 7: Can’t display view

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm trying to display a view with prism region manager. The problem is that Views are added to the RegionManager and ActiveViews is set but nothing is displaying in MainView(StartWindowView).

My Bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper: UnityBootstrapper
{
    private readonly Action<Window> aR;

    public Bootstrapper(Action<Window> AR)
    {
        aR = AR;
    }
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {

        return Container.TryResolve<Views.StartWindowView>();
    }
    protected override void InitializeShell() 
    {
        aR(Container.TryResolve<Views.StartWindowView>());
    }
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        Container.RegisterType(typeof(object),     typeof(Views.TestView),"PlotListView");
        Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Views.SettingsView), "SettingsView");


        Container.RegisterType<IAutoCadService, AutoCadService>
            (new ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterType<IPlotListViewModel, PlotListViewModel>
            (new ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
}
```

My MainWindow(StartWindowView) with RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion":

```
    Window x:Class="PlottingFastAutoCAD2016.Views.StartWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Background="LightSkyBlue"  
        x:Name="window"
        xmlns:res="clr-namespace:PlottingFastAutoCAD2016.ViewModels"
        d:DataContext="{x:Static res:StartWindowViewModelDesign.Instanc}"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        d:DesignHeight="500" 
        d:DesignWidth="600">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Width="50" 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Padding="0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Height="Auto" 
                    Click="Button_Click"
                    Command="{Binding ElementName=window, 
                    Path=DataContext.NavigationCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="PlotListView"
                    Background="Transparent">
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Margin="3">
                        <Image Stretch="Fill"
                               Source="/PlottingFastAutoCAD2016;component/Resources/Icon/printer-.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Plot"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            <Button Width="50" 
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Padding="0"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Height="Auto" 
                    Command="{Binding ElementName=window, 
                    Path=DataContext.NavigationCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="SettingsView"
                    Background="Transparent">
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Margin="3">
                    <Image Stretch="Fill"
                           Source="/PlottingFastAutoCAD2016;component/Resources/Icon/settings.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Settings"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <ItemsControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" 
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      x:Name="contentRegion"
                        />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My ModelView:

```
public class StartWindowViewModel : BindableBase, IStartWindowViewModel 
    {
        private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;

        public StartWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            this.regionManager = regionManager;
            NavigationCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);

        }

        private void Navigate(string uri) 
        {
            regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative), 
                r => {
                    if (r != null) ;
                    //MessageBox.Show("Result: "+r.Result);
                    else MessageBox.Show("Error: " + r.Error.Message);
                });
        }

        public DelegateCommand<string> NavigationCommand { get; set; }
    }
```

Anyone have idea what is going on? I have spent three days to resolve it but no luck.

Comment: What is in `r` when the navigation fails?

Comment: "r" never faild. r.Result is always true.